# AngularJS, Jasmine and Visual Studio 2015 Test Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, jasmine, chutzpah, test-explorer

I am trying to get Jasmine to work with Visual Studio Test Explorer.
So, my test file looked like this:

```
/// <reference path="../wwwroot/lib/angular/angular.min.js" />
/// <reference path="../wwwroot/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js" />
/// <reference path="../wwwroot/lib/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js" />

/// <reference path="../wwwroot/lib/angular-arrays/dist/angular.arrays.js" />
/// <reference path="../wwwroot/lib/angular-simple-cache/dist/simplecache.js" />
/// <reference path="../wwwroot/lib/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.tpls.min.js" />
/// <reference path="../wwwroot/lib/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js" />

/// <reference path="../app/common/common.js" />
/// <reference path="../app/common/services.js" />

var _sharedProductHandler,
    _pricingProducts,
    _availabilityProducts;

beforeEach(module('piiick.common'));
beforeEach(inject(['SharedProductHandler', function (sharedProductHandler) {
    _sharedProductHandler = sharedProductHandler;

    _pricingProducts = [{
        productId: 0
    }];
    _availabilityProducts = [{
        productId: 0
    }];
}]));

describe('Service: SharedProductService', function () {
    it('We have a list of pricing products', function () {
        expect(_pricingProducts.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });

    it('We have a list of availability products', function () {
        expect(_availabilityProducts.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
});
```

If I open in the browser the tests run fine. But I want them to appear in the test explorer. I installed Chutzpah adapter for the test explorer but my tests are not appearing there.
I [read that you can use a chutzpah.json file to add settings](https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chutzpah.json%20Settings%20File), so I did that but I can't get my tests to appear in the test explorer.
I think it is worth mentioning that I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Does anyone know how I can get my tests to show up in the test explorer?

Answer (score 1):

Right, I worked this out.. The chutzpah.json file need to be in the root (it can be anywhere, but the path settings must be relative to wherever the json file is.
Mine looked like this:

```
{
  "Framework": "jasmine",
  "References": [
    { "Path": "wwwroot/lib/angular/angular.min.js" },
    { "Path": "wwwroot/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js" },
    { "Path": "wwwroot/lib/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js" },

    { "Path": "wwwroot/lib/angular-arrays/dist/angular.arrays.js" },
    { "Path": "wwwroot/lib/angular-simple-cache/dist/simplecache.js" },
    { "Path": "wwwroot/lib/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.tpls.min.js" },
    { "Path": "wwwroot/lib/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js" },

    { "Path": "app/common/common.js" },
    { "Path": "app/common/services.js" }
  ],

  "Tests": [
    { "Path": "tests" }
  ]
}
```

the spec files no longer need any references, so that can look like this:

```
var _sharedProductHandler,
    _pricingProducts,
    _availabilityProducts;

beforeEach(module('piiick.common'));
beforeEach(inject(['SharedProductHandler', function (sharedProductHandler) {
    _sharedProductHandler = sharedProductHandler;

    _pricingProducts = [{
        productId: 0
    }];
    _availabilityProducts = [{
        productId: 0
    }];
}]));

describe('Service: SharedProductService', function () {
    it('We have a list of pricing products', function () {
        expect(_pricingProducts.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });

    it('We have a list of availability products', function () {
        expect(_availabilityProducts.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
});
```

and just for my own reference, the bower.json only needs these two:

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.5.5",
    "jasmine": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "ignore": [
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out!